# OP was credited for my edit

Tags: discussion, editing

Very strange.

A few minutes ago, I made an edit to a question. I added the hyperlink to a Wikipedia definition (for sourcing) and slightly changed formatting.

Here is my revision (#2):

https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/297201/revisions

Yet, it says that the OP was the person who made the edit. I know it's my edit because it has my reasoning:

> I provided the link to the included quote (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma).

The only thing that I didn't write in the edit that is shown in the edit is adding the word "more."

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: This link http://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/158378 shows that the edit was approved by one member before it was rejected by the OP (represented by *Community ♦* ). It could be that the OP didn't understand how to proceed forward, it could be that the OP made a genuine mistake, or it could be he felt irked by the edit and wanted to do that him/herself. But it does, occasionally happen. Not often, but if a newcomer doesn't realize that an edit from an outsider does not rob that poster of authorship, they could feel insulted, or confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have more than [2,000 reputation points](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) to edit any post without going through a peer review. If 2 reviewers accept (reject), your edit will be posted (rejected).

Now, after you finished your edit and submitted it for a peer review, the OP could see the change as it is notified to the OP by a message. The OP has 4 options, **Approve**, **Reject**, and **Improve Edit** (suggested by you), and do nothing.

1. If the OP doesn't do anything and your edit is approved by 2 other users, your edit will be posted. You will receive 2 reputation points.
2. If the OP clicks on "Improve Edit", your edit will be reflected right under the OP's edit in the revision history and 2 rep points will be given to you.
3. However, if the OP rejects your edit and uses your contribution (links and changes) in his/her own edit, your display name will not appear in the revision history, nor will 2 rep points be given to you.

The OP typed "more" additionally to your edit and clicked on **Save Edits** and the No. 3 above happened.

It doesn't happen very often and there is nothing you can do about it. We can never know whether the OP did it intentionally or not. It could be just coincidence.

For further information, please visit [Help Center > Our model](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/editing).

Comment: So, you are saying that the OP manually copy and pasted my edits, to a T? And then also manually copied my edit summary explanation? Isn't this rather strange/nonsensical behavior? Since this behavior is so deliberate, I cannot see how it could possibly be a coincidence.

Comment: @Kyle Based on my experience, it rarely happens. You don't need to judge the OP's behavior. Nobody knows what happened exactly except for the fact that the OP rejected your edit. And there is nothing we can do about it. The OP has as much right over his post as other users like you and me. As time goes by, you will learn more with more experience.